# Waiting for file to be closed in spawned browser

Tags: browser, mfc, spawn

I invoke a instance of a browser like this:

```
if (bResult)
{
    DWORD dwResult;

    strProgram.Format(_T("%s \"%s\""), (LPCTSTR)it->strPath, (LPCTSTR)m_strTempPreviewHTML);
    theApp.ExecuteProgram(strProgram, dwResult);
}
```

For normal applications my main executable will wait until the process has finished. But this is not so with a browser.

Is it possible to wait until the file has been closed in the spawned browser?

Comment: There is no easy way to wait on a file being closed. Presumably you want to do this to clean up the temporary file. In that case, you can try to create the file with the [`FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) flag. You'll still run into timing issues when passing it off to executables, that launch surrogate processes (as is common with browsers).

Comment: You may consider opening the file in an embedded browser window. This way you have full control.

Comment: @zett42 I already have an embedded browser window (the `CHtmlView` control). But I offer to spawn out to a actual browser because the internal viewer has issues with 4K monitors and printing. The reason I was wanting to wait was because the user might spawn a preview more than once. Each time they spawn the preview it will deleting the existing file and re-create it. Not a big issue I suppose. When my own editor shuts down it again deletes any temporary file if it is still there.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for your suggestion. I think I am just going to leave it as it is.